# Ways to deal with violence and anger management

Tags: virtual-reality

After watching Star Trek, I was thinking it would be nice if there were a room where you could simulate the shapes of people you had a problem with and as soon as you would go to hit them with a weapon the 3D image would turn into a coca cola can or something similar, and then you would hit it and it would break.

The reason I bring this up is I cannot think of a better way to deal with anger management. This may work for someone. I have seen videos of people beating old computers for a kick. Not sure if it's the same thing.

Sorry if this post is cr*, sorry, I don't know what to do about it.

EDIT:

I am mostly interested with this scenario:

Anger becomes a problem when it creates trouble for you with other people

You are getting angry with the people who are closest to you, or with people who are less powerful than you, rather than dealing with the situation that sparked off your anger in the first place.

EDIT:

I am trying to say that in my opinion anger "management" may not always be an appropriate solution. Sometimes you need a mechanism to let things out: soccer, rugby, boxing, but I believe one can do even better. I do not believe this letting Pitt to be harmful to life and relationships.

I have an inkling that a computer simulation could help in relieving these symptoms, gradually, over time, in a manner where the intensity of anger graph would be similar to the position of a damped pendulum over time.

Then there is the cross cultural issue, that different so-called cultures deal with having to deal with one's emotions or another in set patterns, and law enforcement goes along with this (admittedly not knowing what to do about it), but this does not leave a chance for everyone.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but you don't seem to be asking a question. Do you want to know whether this would be an effective method of anger management? What effect it might have on interpersonal relationships? Unless you have an actual question then I'm afraid this is off topic.

Comment: This is a question of psychology. You suggest anger management can be dealt with by acting out. This is a debunked idea. Suggestions for anger management can be found here. http://www.psychology.org.au/publications/tip_sheets/anger/ You might Google "anger management" to find more information on the topic.

Comment: I have updated my post to make our clearer. The post also says " Anger can also result from misunderstandings or poor communication between people.". What if someone believes it and then after two years of trying, they still find the communication ineffective?

Comment: I would also add, that the article did not consider "being angry at one's self", which, in some situations, could, be positive in obtaining the desired result.

Comment: IMHO, four out of six of the supplied management techniques, listed at the bottom, are helpful, and the article sheds light on various spectra related to what may be perceived as anger, or may be considered anger, that I was familiar with. Great as a starting point for a psychologist trying to address the issue, although perhaps a bit focused.

Answer (score 1):

While this might be one way to deal with anger (in various versions of Star Trek people could go on the holodeck and interact with computer simulations of real or imaginary people), it should not be the only way.

If you are very angry at a person at the beginning of a watch, you will have to keep your rage bottled up inside until you are off shift before you can take any effective measures. People going around nursing hurt feelings or a grudge in the middle of a watch might not be able to respond to a real emergency during their watch.

As wel, if you are socialized to deal with a problem by punching it in the nose, then the solution to more and more problems could become the same. IF a holodeck is not available, or you have been essentially conditioned to thinking this is the only way to deal with issues, you might not want to go to the holodeck, but "deal" with the issue right on the spot.

Frankly, anger management and other control issues can be dealt with in numerous ways, ranging from meditation, neural programming, mediation and talking, or transferring the feelings to another object or task (a Vulcan crushing a stress ball into powder might be a warning sign for the rest of the crew....)

So study the multitude of techniques to deflect or diffuse feelings which affect performance on duty.

Comment: I would like to address the osu where there may be many people, but none of them the right one to talk.

Comment: Anyways, I only have a marginal interest in psychology, and really don't want to bother.